# Combining Neural Networks Pytorch

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, computer-vision, pytorch, convolution

I have **2 images** as input, **x1** and **x2**  and try to use convolution as a **similarity measure**. The idea is that the learned weights substitute more traditional measure of similarity (cross correlation, NN, ...). Defining my forward function as follows:

```
def forward(self,x1,x2):
    out_conv1a = self.conv1(x1)
    out_conv2a = self.conv2(out_conv1a)
    out_conv3a = self.conv3(out_conv2a)

    out_conv1b = self.conv1(x2)
    out_conv2b = self.conv2(out_conv1b)
    out_conv3b = self.conv3(out_conv2b)
```

Now for the similarity measure:

```
out_cat = torch.cat([out_conv3a, out_conv3b],dim=1)
futher_conv = nn.Conv2d(out_cat)
```

**My question is as follows:**

1) Would Depthwise/Separable Convolutions as in the google [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1706.03059.pdf) yield any advantage over 2d convolution of the concatenated input. For that matter can convolution be a similarity measure, cross correlation and convolution are very similar.

2) It is my understanding that the groups=2 option in conv2d would provide 2 separate inputs to train weights with, in this case each of the previous networks weights. How are these combined afterwards?

For a basic concept see [here](https://www.quora.com/What-are-Siamese-neural-networks-what-applications-are-they-good-for-and-why).

Comment: a) I am not sure, how are you using convolution to compute correlation? Convolution is similar to correlation, yes, but the correlation between weight filter and input, not two concatenated inputs. 
b) When you use group=2, you do not need to combine the output, it is already combined, if you are asking that. But I am not sure what "input" is provided by conv2d, it only provides weights

Comment: Thanks for the answer! a) I am not trying to compute correlation but define a similarity measure by convolution, ie learnable weights, but I am not certain this is reasonable. b) The input would be the concatenated layers of out_conv3a, out_conv3b so a set of learnable parameters.

Comment: http://vis-www.cs.umass.edu/bcnn/ might be an idea, bilinear pooling would just be the outer product of the matrices

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a `nn.Conv2d` layer you assume weights are trainable parameters. However, if you want to filter one feature map with another, you can dive deeper and use [`torch.nn.functional.conv2d`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.functional.conv2d) to explicitly define both input and filter yourself:

```
out = torch.nn.functional.conv2d(out_conv3a, out_conv3b)
```

Comment: well that's what I am using, or would this replace concat? If so whats the advantage?